# XML Schema (XSD): How to express "At most one element from group A and at most one element from group b"?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, schema, unique

Say I have two sets of XML elements:

```
<One/>
<Two/>
<Three/>
```

And

```
<A/>
<B/>
<C/>
```

And I want to have them as children of a bucket element:

```
<Bucket>
   <A/>
   <One/>
</Bucket>
```

Or

```
<Bucket>
   <C/>
   <Two/>
</Bucket>
```

But I don't want to allow more than one element from either set of elements. I.e:

```
<Bucket>
   <A/>
   <B/>
   <One/>
</Bucket>
```

and

```
<Bucket>
   <A/>
   <One/>
   <Two/>
</Bucket>
```

would be invalid. How might I express this in my XML Schema?

I thought to try `xs:unique` but that prevents `name()` and `local-name()` usage in the field or selector.

**UPDATE**

The full solution is:

```
<xs:element name="Bucket">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="A"/>
        <xs:element name="B"/>
        <xs:element name="C"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="One"/>
        <xs:element name="Two"/>
        <xs:element name="Three"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Do you allow none from a group? As in, is `<Bucket><A/></Bucket>` acceptable?

Comment: yes. that would be acceptable as well as `<Bucket><One/></Bucket>`

Comment: Nice question .. +1 , also made fav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with something like,

```
<xs:element name="Bucket">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="A"/>
        <xs:element name="B"/>
        <xs:element name="C"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="One"/>
        <xs:element name="Two"/>
        <xs:element name="Three"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But probably with better types defined to represent the choices instead of having them inline like that. But the general idea is the same.

By default, `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are set to `1`, so by default this doesn't permit multiples of each type to be present. It also means they aren't optional. If you want either group to be optional, you should add `minOccurs='0'` to the `<xs:choice>` element.

Comment: Hmm...This does not seem to be valid. One `xs:choice` is allowed, but two (without a container) is not. I also tried nesting choices, but neither seems to be valid in my editor (vs2010).

Comment: Yeah...I think i was making it harder than it was. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ee: I tossed in the sequence for you. Sorry about that, but I was too busy at the time to test the code myself. Thanks for the heads up.